# Restangular put() not working on multiple put()'s

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Here is the code in question

```
function putCategory(category) {
        console.log(category.parent_id);
        category.put().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.parent_id);
            delete category._updating;
            angular.extend(category, data);
            updateCategories();
        }, function (error) {
            delete category._updating;
            category.errors = readError(error);
        });
    }
```

Here is a brief example of the problem:

- initial state: parent_id = null (it is a root category)
- change the parent_id to 1, and call putCategory.
- The category updates properly (parent_id = 1).
- Decide that I want parent_id to be 2 instead. Call putCategory again.
- The category does not update, and stays in the same state (parent_id = 1). No further updates seem to stick.
- If I refresh the page, parent_id is still 1. So at least the first put() worked
- I can then make another change, and it will work, but a second (or third etc) will not. So I can change it back to null, or to 2, but any additional change will not work unless I refresh it again. Basically get 1 proper put request per object per page load.

When I inspect the console logs, the input data is correct (the first console log), and the second console log is correct the first time, and wrong the second time  (and later).

When I look at the network tab, I can see that the outgoing params are also correct the first time, and wrong in the second.

So as best I can tell, the put() call is not working properly, does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restangular does some tricky things with the `this` binding of the elements (see [Copying elements](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#copying-elements) for another problematic scenario).
The problem is most likely in your call `angular.extend(category, data);`. This call copies all enumerable properties (including Restangular methods), while it would be enough to update the fields (e.g. id, name, date) of the element.

The most easy solution for this is to use the `plain()` function of your response. This function returns the pure data object you received, so you can use it to copy exclusively your data fields.

```
category.put().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.parent_id);
            delete category._updating;
            angular.extend(category, data.plain());
            updateCategories();
        });
```

Comment: This made for a good start to my Monday, it worked perfectly. Just to clarify, the plain() call is going to ONLY return the fields for category, and not all the other angular/restangular stuff? Also, apparently I cannot +1 you yet, but I have accepted your answer. Thanks

Comment: Great, you're welcome! :-) Yes, `plain()` returns your object *excluding* the restangular stuff.