# restangular save ignores changes to restangular object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to call save on a restangularized object, but the save method is completely ignoring any changes made to the object, it seems to have bound the original unmodified object.

When I run this in the debugger I see that when my saveSkill method (see below) is entered right before I call save on it the skill object will reflect the changes I made to it's name and description fields.  If I then do a "step into" I go into Restangular.save method.  However, the 'this' variable within the restangular.save method has my old skill, with the name and description equal to whatever they were when loaded.  It's ignoring the changes I made to my skill.

The only way I could see this happening is if someone called bind on the save, though I can't why rectangular would do that?  My only guess is it's due to my calling $object, but I can't find much in way of documentation to confirm this.

I'm afraid I can't copy and paste, all my code examples are typed by hand so forgive any obvious syntax issues as typos.  I don't know who much I need to describe so here is the shortened version, I can retype more if needed:

```
state('skill.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    data: {pageTitle: 'Skill Detail'},
    tempalte: 'template.tpl.html'
    controller: 'SkillFormController',
    resolve: {
         isCreate: (function(){ return false;}, 
         skill: function(SkillService, $stateParams){
             return SkillService.get($stateParams.id, {"$expand": "people"}).$object;
    },
  });

 my SkillService looks like this:

 angular.module('project.skill').('SkillService', ['Restangular, function(Retangular) {
   var route="skills";

   var SkillService= Restangular.all(route);

   SkillService.restangularize= function(element, parent) {
       var skill=Restangular.restangluarizeElement(parent, elment, route);
       return skill;
   };

   return SkillService;
 }];
```

Inside of my template.tpl.html I have your standard text boxes bound to name and description, and a save button.  The save button calls saveSkill(skill) of my SkillFormController which looks like this:

```
 $scope.saveSkill=function(skill) {
 skill.save().then(function returnedSkill) {
      toaster.pop('success', "YES!", returnedSkill.name + " saved.");
      ...(other irrelevant stuff)
  };
```

If it matters I have an addElementTransformer hook that runs a method calling skilll.addRestangularMethod() to add a getPeople method to all skill objects.  I don't include the code since I doubt it's relevant, but if needed to I can elaborate on it.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570897/restangular-put-not-working-on-multiple-puts). Restangular does indeed bind `this` manually, so it can be that the object sent is really the unmodified one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work, though I honestly still don't know entirely why it works I know the fix I used.

First, as stated in comments restangular does bind all of it's methods to the original restangularizedObject.  This usually works since it's simply aliasing the restangularied object, so long as you use that object your modifications will work.

This can be an issue with Restangular.copy() vs angular.copy.  Restangualar.copy() makes sure to restangularize the copied object properly, rebinding restangualr methods to the new copy objects.  If you call only Angular.copy() instead of Restangualar.copy() you will get results like mine above.

However, I was not doing any copy of the object (okay, I saved a master copy to revert to if cancel was hit, but that used Restangular.copy() and besides which wasn't being used in my simple save scenario).

As far as I can tell my problem was using the .$object call on the restangular promise.  I walked through restangular enough to see it was doing some extra logic restangularizing methods after a promise returns, but I didn't get to the point of following the $object's logic.  However, replacing the $object call with a then() function that did nothing but save the returned result has fixed my issues.  If someone can explain how I would love to update this question, but I can't justify using work time to try to further hunt down a fixed problem even if I really would like to understand the cause better.

Comment: I just has this issue as well, the `$object` behaviour is severely broken!